# Unable to get correct result from simple query in cmd PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, sqlplus

I was trying to print "Hello World", but I continue to get number 7 returned.  Also, after the 7 is returned, I cannot run another file without restarting cmd window. If I hit enter key, the number increments by 1.  Please explain why this is happening and possible ways to correct.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Put a `/` on a new line at the end of the file to terminate the PL/SQL anonymous block.

```sql
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

DECLARE
  name VARCHAR2(20);
BEGIN
  name := 'Hello World';
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(name);
END;
/
```

SQL/Plus has read your file but has not found the statement terminator for the PL/SQL block so it is continuing to ask for more input to complete the statement. It is expecting a `/` character on a new line (the 7th line of the statement, the first being `DECLARE` as the `SET` command is a different statement) and when you press the enter key then it moves on to line 8 of the statement and is still expecting the terminator character so asks for more input (and repeats for the 9th, 10th and 11th lines).

You could press `/` then enter in SQL/Plus but it would be better to fix the file so it contains complete statements.

Comment: Thank you so much for a great explanation!